# Method to create a Tournament Bracket on Fragment

Tags: android

I am making a Ping Pong score keeper app and I have a fragment that will be dedicated to showing a view of the current bracket in its state at the time it is viewed. I am having some trouble figuring out to display something like this. My hope is that I can make it look like a traditional tournament bracket in a horizontal tree diagram-like form. Does anyone have any methods/techniques/solutions on how to easily do this? Or is there maybe a library to make this easier?

Comment: Did you find the solution yet? I never found a solution with canvas or anything so I created a project which displays tournament brackets using fragment and viewpager. You can find the project here https://github.com/Emil333/TournamentBrackets . Hope this helps you

Comment: @EmilPradeep Hello! Thanks so much! I actually used something extremely similar to that solution: Fragment, Viewpager, and CardViews. The animations are very cool though! Thank you for that! I will save that for future reference.